# Unable to use multiple proxies with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer

What is the best way to set up multiple proxies with puppeteer? I tried the following:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    (async () => {
        let browsers = [];
        const proxies = [
            'socks5://myuser:mypass@host:port',
            'socks5://myuser:mypass@host:port',
            'socks5://myuser:mypass@host:port',
               ];
    const openWindow = async (proxy) => {
            try {
                const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, args: [`--proxy-server=${proxy}`] });
                const page = await browser.newPage();
                browsers.push({ browser, page });
                page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    
                await page.setViewport({
                    width: 992,
                    height: 607
                });
    
                await page.goto('chrome://new-tab-page/', { waitUntil: 'load' });
                await page.goto('https://dnsleaktest.com/', { waitUntil: 'load' });
    console.log(`Window opened with proxy: ${proxy}`);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error opening window with proxy ${proxy}: ${error}`);
            }
        };
    
        // Open windows with proxies
        const openWindowPromises = proxies.map(proxy => openWindow(proxy));
        await Promise.all(openWindowPromises);
    
        console.log('All windows opened or skipped due to dead proxies.');
    })();
```

**However, it does not work and I get the following message instead:**

```
Error: net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES at https://dnsleaktest.com
```

**Background:** The application previously worked with a single proxy configuration, but the issue arose when attempting to introduce support for multiple proxies.
Each scraper instance runs in its Chrome window, with one proxy configured per window for isolation and parallel scraping purposes.

**Working! Single Window Code:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const proxy = 'myip:myport';
const username = 'myusername';
const password = 'mypassword';

(async () => {
    // Pass proxy URL into the --proxy-server arg
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [`--proxy-server=${proxy}`],
        headless: false,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage()
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

    // Authenticate your proxy with the username and password defined above
    await page.authenticate({ username, password });

    await page.goto('https://dnsleaktest.com');

    
})();
```

Comment: The proxy configuration is different in the two files, maybe that's something to do with it.

Comment: okay but how can I do the same with a single window code? because my first multiple code is not working

Comment: Maybe do the same proxy configuration logic in both versions? I mean, the logic that works :)

Comment: I Tried but it giving me same error ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES i still dont know how to solve this issue, thanks

Comment: I used Puppeteer-page-proxy, it worked but Google and YouTube are not opening. Now the new error is showing Error: net::ERR_FAILED at https://youtube.com/

Answer (score -1):

I solved it myself

> I Just put socks:// instead of socks5://